# Why do I not see my business code in Crash Stack reports from Google play

Tags: android, stack-trace, crash-reports

Whoever has an experience with fixing unhandled exception crashes from user field reports, which are visible in Android Developers Console on-line:

An example of stack from reported crash:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod (View.java:5070)
  at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (View.java:5029)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:6199)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:23637)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6732)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

I just do not get a single useful information, all stack traces are from inner Android Development Kit code. Therefore I can't figure where in my own code does the exception fire.

It might well be a question of proper setting, to report more stack frames.
Got no idea how to increase # of reported stack frames.

I did not find any helpful info on android support pages.
The only suspect I have is the report could be "obfuscated"
However, this report does not look much obfuscated. Does it ? :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the system cannot find the `onClick` method you declared in xml. (See [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-8.1.0_r23/core/java/android/view/View.java#5406))

In general I recommend using a crash reporting library like [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) or [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/), which will provide you with more context than the play console.

Disclaimer: I am the current maintainer of ACRA.